# Handling Data between ViewScoped ManagedBeans

Tags: view, parameters, jsf-2, scope, managed-bean

I am trying to do smth like this:

```
@ViewScoped
public class Bean2{
     public void saveChanges(){
         //saving changes...
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().put("id",id);
         FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect("page1");
     }
}
```

and in Bean1 to fetch data from requestMap

```
@ViewScoped
public class Bean1{
    public Bean1(){
         String id =  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestMap().get(id);
    }
}
```

But id is allways NULL and RequestMap is empty.
I tried with getRequestParameterMap() it's also empty...
Do u know how to solve this problem without changing scope of beans and without using getSessionMap.put(parameters)...?
Thnx

Answer (score 1):

The request map is specific to the HTTP request. A redirect instructs the browser to send a **new** request. A new request means also a new map.

The request parameter map is a mapping of, well, the request parameters. So you could pass it as a request parameter instead.

```
redirect("page1?id=" + id);
```

This way it's available by the request parameter map of the new request.